# How can I use the Implicit Function Theorem without hypothesis about the Jacobian be invertible

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem

> Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x) = f(x) + (f(x))^5$. If $g \in C^r$ then $f \in C^r$.

This question is of my practice list of Implicit Function Theorem, but I cannot see how I use the IFT in this question. Can someone help me? I dont want a complete solution, but, at least, a hint about how apply the IFT to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider the function $\phi\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, $\phi(t)=t+t^5$. Can you express $g$ in terms of $\phi$ and $f$? What do you need to express $f$ in terms of $\phi$ and $g$?

Comment: $g(x) = f(x) + (f(x))^5 = \phi(f(x))$ so, if $\phi$ is invertible, $f(x) = \phi^{-1}(\phi(f(x))) = \phi^{-1}(g(x))$. Thus, its enough show that $\phi^{-1} \in C^r$. Is correct?

Comment: Right. In fact, if $\phi$ is invertible, since $\phi$ is $C^\infty$, so is $\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes. I thought it was necessary to use the IFT. Thank you!

Comment: Implicit and Inverse Function Theorems are always interchangeable :P